# CommandError: 'D:\Python\Project\resume_1' already exists

Tags: python, django

I am creating a django project. I can successfully create virtual environment and pip install django, but when I try to create project using

```
django-admin startproject resume_1
```

There is an error that showed

```
CommandError: 'D:\Python\Project\resume_1' already exists
```

I tried uninstalling django twice but it only allowed me to uninstall once, so it is likely not about duplicate django, I also checked the lib\site-packages, there are no duplicated folders or folders either.

However, I do have two versions of python right now, one installed along with anaconda, one is separated from anaconda and directly downloaded from *python.org*. Right now, I am just using the separate python, I even checked the python version, and the pip version, so it should be fine. Still, I could be wrong since I am not that experienced.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that the project you are creating (`resume_1`) already exists on your disk. You can either use the existing project that can be found in `D:\Python\Project\resume_1` or by creating a new project with different name/path.

Comment: but it shouldn't be, there are no files that have a 'resume' file name. Moreover, I can't just use this file either, because it is not a Django project yet, it doesn't even have `manage.py` in it.